# How can I integrate CSS/JS/Image preprocessors with django.contrib.staticfiles?

Tags: javascript, css, django, media

In Django 1.3, `django.contrib.staticfiles` provides a nice "blessed" solution to managing static files, like a site's CSS, Javascript, and images.

However, I don't see an obvious way to integrate arbitrary static file preprocessors (concat/minify CSS/JS, spritesheet autogen a la [SmartSprite](http://csssprites.org/), etc.) with the staticfiles app.

Do any projects/snippets/solutions exist for this that will integrate well with `django.contrib.staticfiles`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[django-compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor) have support for this, asking you to [add 'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder' to the  STATICFILES_FINDERS](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/) setting.  I guess you can use or spy their code to see what they have done to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

django-compressor is definitely my preferred option because of how easy it is to just wrap blocks of css and js includes and have them compressed, however it does not do sprite sheets.

So you could either build in an additional processor to django-compressor using [spritesticker](http://code.google.com/p/spritesticker/) or use [django-media-bundler](https://github.com/rnk/django-media-bundler) instead which does both but takes more effort to setup.